# Can I customize the icon of "Code, Split, Design" in Android Studio 3.6?

Tags: android-studio

I update Android Studio to V3.6, I find the icon of "Code, Split, Design"  is located top-right corner.

Can I customize the icon  "Code, Split, Design"  and make it located bottom-left corner? You can see Image A.

**Image A**

[image: -st]

Comment: I don't think the current layout of the icon is good,  I have to move a long distance to click the icon if I use a larger screen.

Comment: Every other icon/setting seems movable, but these do not :-(

Comment: And it takes a WHOLE row of screen space. It drives me nuts!

Comment: Is there a way to hide this bar? It takes a whole line of screen space and its empty mostly

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively, you can use keyboard shortcut to navigate quickly between "Code, Split, Design" without using the mouse. The shortcut on Windows is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd>.

Comment: on Mac it's: Shift + Control + Left/Right.